# Will ROC curve for a model always be symmetric if we have enough training data?

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, roc, auc

ROC curve usually looks like the following figure:

[image: ROC curve]

If we have enough data, could we safely assume that ROC curve for a model will always be symmetric around the line y = 100 - x? If not, is there any way to make the ROC curve shift up (the red line)?

I am asking this question because my final goal is to optimize sensitivity at a minimum specificity. However, using sensitivity as my evaluation metric seems to be very similar to using AUC. So, I am wondering whether using AUC is highly correlated with using sensitivity as an evaluation metric because you can not intentionally tweak the shape of ROC curve.

I also tried using sample weight, but it seems to only impact the cutoff of the classification model. Please check [my attempts](https://rawgit.com/ajing/MachineLearningExperiments/master/CostSensitiveLearning/01_model_building_with_weight_to_change_ROC_curve.html) with SVM by changing the weight of the positive class.

Comment: It's ROC curve, not AUC curve. AUC is a single statistic you compute from the curve.

Comment: No, it won't always be symmetric. It depends on the distribution of the "score" that generates the curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the ROC curve does not need to be symmetric.

Take as an example a dataset with a binary dependent variable $y$ and a single binary independent variable $x$. Assume that $y=1$ whenever $x=1$ and that $y$ is randomly selected when $x=0$, taking value 1 with probability 0.5 and taking value 0 with probability 0.5. Assume $x=1$ for 1/3 of the observations and $x=0$ for 2/3 of the observations.

No matter how much data you have, any sensible model will have an ROC curve like the following:

[image]

Basically you can identify half of the positives with no errors using the observations with $x=1$, and the rest of the selection is more or less random. The ROC curve from your model will not be symmetric regardless of the size of the training set.

Comment: Do you mean "half of the samples"? "Half of the positives" mean you have 50% accuracy in your positive samples (you have 100%).

Comment: @StudentT I mean "half of the positives," not "half of the samples." 1/3 of the samples have (x, y)=(1, 1), 1/3 have (x, y)=(0, 1) and 1/3 have (x, y)=(0, 0). You can therefore identify half of the positive samples by labeling everything with x=1 as being a positive observation. This corresponds to the point with TPR=0.5 and FPR=0.

Comment: You are right, but it's there any way in model building that we can purposely change the ROC curve? i.e., fixed FPR, optimizing TPR.

Comment: @user2149631 I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Anyhow, in the example dataset I provided it is pretty clear that no model can improve over the plotted curve, aka that curve represents the maximum achievable TPR for every FPR.